# next.jdbc managing connection to the database?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I have a mini clojure app which looks at the DB to get some data.

I have set the maximum connections in the pool to 5. This is the limit for my cloud DB.

here is the code:

```
(ns report-app.core
  (:require [http.async.client :as http]
            [next.jdbc :as j]
            [next.jdbc.connection :as connection])
  (:import (com.zaxxer.hikari HikariDataSource)))

(def db-spec (connection/->pool com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
                   {...connection data here... 
                    :dataSourceProperties {:MaximumPoolSize 5}}))


(def pool (j/get-datasource db-spec))

(def to-validate (j/execute! pool ["

select * from raw_data
 limit 3

"]))
```

The problem I am having is that when I am working with this application, evaluating forms and testing... all my connections are taken up. That means my other apps get "too many connections to xyz database"

My question here is, how do I close connections after I have evaluated a form? And what is the best way of managing connections with next.jdbc in clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the full datasource to `j/execute!`, it should open and close connections for you. Since you setup connection pooling which looks just like [next.jdbc documentation on datasources and connections](https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/blob/develop/doc/getting-started.md#datasources-connections--transactions).

Maybe you are evaluating the form multiple times and creating more than one connection pool. You can try wrapping the usage of the data pool in a [`with-open`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-open), as described in [next.jdbc documentation on connection pooling](https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/blob/develop/doc/getting-started.md#connection-pooling).

```clj
(with-open [^HikariDataSource ds (connection/->pool HikariDataSource db-spec)] 
  ...)
```

What you can also try is explicitly getting a connection using `j/get-connection` and wrapping the `execute!` in a `with-open`:

```clj
(def to-validate 
  (with-open [conn (j/get-connection pool)
    (j/execute! conn ["select * from raw_data limit 3"])))
```

This way the connection is closed manually and you could reuse the connection.

Comment: Just to clarify, what does `^HikariDataSource` mean?

Comment: It's a [type hint](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#typehints) for the Clojure compiler. It's not necessary and I think it's added only for clarity.